# Pass several data from Mat Dialog Angular 4 back to parent

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an mat dialog component in my project 
as I press Confirm button I call

```
  onCloseConfirm(data) {
    this.thisDialogRef.close('Confirm');
    console.log("conf data", data);
  }
```

in my parent I subscribe to passed data (in my Case 'Confirm');

```
   dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log(`Dialog closed: ${result}`);
});
```

What I would like to do is to pass `data` also. So I would like to pass the `'Confrim'` message + `data` both. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

You can pass anything to the `close` method, so you could pass something like this:

```
 onCloseConfirm(data) {
    this.thisDialogRef.close({
       message: 'Confirm',
       data
    });
    console.log("conf data", data);
  }
```

And then, in the afterClosed handler:

```
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
  console.log(`Dialog closed: ${result.message}`, result.data);
});
```